# Exception loading .jsonl files in PySpark 1.5.1

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I'm trying to load a set of .jsonl files (newline delimited jsons) into Spark 1.5.1 (using PySpark specifically) - and save them back out as Parquet files. Here's the high-order code:

```
print "Loading: " + path
schemaString = "data name version"

fields = StructType([StructField(field_name, StringType(), True) for field_name in schemaString.split(" ")])
dataJson = sqlContext.read.json(path, fields).cache()

parqPath = constructParqPath(path)
print "ParqPath: " + parqPath
dataJson.write.parquet(parqPath)
```

I get the following exception when I run the code using submit-spark:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String
```

How can I either explicitly cast or properly load the data in?

Comment: I think the exception seems pretty straightforward. What does a sample of your data look like? Is it possible the either of the "data" or "version" fields is an integer?

Comment: It might be empty or let's assume that it is - what would be the proper way to deal with this? Is there a way to pass a parsing function / logic on how to deal with exceptions/errors when loading data?